# Read and Write file in java whilst keeping the special characters

Tags: java, file, encoding, fileutils

After reading and writing the file, the bullet points get replaced with symbolic unreadable text `"ï¿½"`. Here is the code:

```
String str = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File(sourcePath), "UTF-8");         
nextTextFile.append(redactStrings(str, redactedStrings));
FileUtils.writeStringToFile(new File(targetPath), nextTextFile.toString());
```

[Link to sample file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1HqDP7Ho33wugqQMyIDLFybL8K6oiyEfo/view?usp=sharing)

[generated file with funny characters](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1h0CyIdmbl-i-jnTkg_M8FWQteO4IkZF8/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: In what environment is the file stored? Windows? Linux/Unix? What is the default encoding?

Comment: Linux/Unix but I want it to be platform independent

Comment: Then please post an example of the file that is read and undesirably re-encoded. What Java version do you use?

Comment: I am using Java version 1.8.0_144

Comment: Is there a reason why you use `org.apache.commons.io.FileUtils` instead of `java.nio.file.Files.readAllLines()`? Is your source file really encoded in UTF-8?

Comment: No particular reason. I am open to using a different class. The source file was created from a word document. I am sure of the encoding

Comment: Then check my answer which is using `java.nio` in order to read and write files.

Answer (score 0):

I checked it out on Windows and if the source file is encoded in UTF-8, the following code will produce the desired output to the console and to a file, which is then encoded in UTF-8 as well, making use of `java.nio`:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Path inPath = Paths.get(sourcePath);
    Path outPath = Paths.get(targetPath);

    try {
        List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(inPath, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

        lines.forEach(line -> {
            System.out.println(line);
        });

        Files.write(outPath, lines, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Please note that the source file has to be encoded in UTF-8, otherwise this may throw an `IOException` stating something like `Input length = 1`. Play around with the `StandardCharsets` if it does not meet your requirements or make sure **the encoding of the source file is UTF-8**.

Comment: I get the error java.nio.charset.MalformedInputException: Input length = 1

Comment: Then try another charset... Maybe an ISO